# Can't boot after inserting HDD

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bios

I got one 320GB laptop HDD. But there is one problem: Both laptop and PC stuck at bios screen when I connect that HDD. Here is photo of HDD with all details:
[image]

Comment: If two PCs are affected this usually means that the HDD is defect. You can try an external SATA-to-USB connector and attach the drive at run-time to check if this works

Comment: Is there any other ways? Cuz I don't know where find it.

Comment: Make sure to test different SATA cables, just in case the problem is the cable and not the drive. But if this does not help and you don't even reach the BIOS then something is wrong with the HDD.

Comment: Then it is defect of HDD. Thanks for you attention.